# Closing keyboard after button click (breaks if no EditText is focused on)

Tags: java, android

I put this on my button listener:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

It works perfectly for when the keyboard is up: it closes the keyboard and then continues its execution. The problem is that when no `EditText` was ever pressed (none of them are highlighted/focused on), it breaks and the app "stops working".

I guess it would be nice if I could check if an EditText had ever been pressed.

I tried to do this to check:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

if (imm.isActive()) // returns true if any view is currently active in the input method
{
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
}
```

**EDIT**

I ended up doing this:

I created this method:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard (Activity activity, View view) 
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

I then called the `method` in my button listener like this:

```
hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this, v); // MainActivity is the name of my class and v is the View I used in my button listener method.
```

Comment: Did you check the logCat, what error does it show?

Comment: @NiteshVerma I'm not familiar with logCat. I did find a mediocre solution, though, I'll post.

Comment: Use Full Link

   Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: @NiteshVerma Yes. I know it's there, I just haven't bothered to learn it. I suppose I could just copy+paste though.

Answer (score 0):

Mediocre/bad solution, because it doesn't work as general as I want it to:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

EditText x = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
x.requestFocus(); // this way no matter what, an EditText is focused on.

imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
```