# Removing focus from multiple EditText in layout on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I can remove focus from EditText in layout if it is only one field using this:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

But if I add more, it keeps focusing on later one.

Comment: Provide your XML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out

```xml
<requestFocus/>
```

---

from each EditText in your XML.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295802/how-to-make-edittext-not-focused-when-creating-activity/18295935#18295935) and [possibly that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415793/closing-keyboard-after-button-click-breaks-if-no-edittext-is-focused-on/18415957#18415957) which helped me.

Summary of the links above:

add these properties to your Relative or Linear Layout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

So for example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```